# Zend Studio cannot detect Zend Server

Tags: php, zend-studio, zend-server

**PHP Version 5.3.1, Zend Studio 7.1.1.v20091227**

**Zend Server Community Edition 5.0 (Build: ZendServer-CE-5.0.0GA_RC181-5.3.1-Windows_x86)**

**Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8k**

**Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit**

I have installed Zend Studio, downloaded and installed Zend Server.  Zend Studio does not automatically detect Zend Sever.  When Zend Studio is started I am getting the following warning bubble

> No local installation of Zend Server
>   was detected. Click here to find out
>   more about Zend Server.

The Zend Server is definately up and running correctly.  I am able to use the Zend Server web interface and run my PHP applications without any problems.

I have tried manually adding a server in Zend Studio by the following steps:

1. Servers > New Server
2. Add Server Name = Zend Server
3. URL document root = http://localhost
4. Finish
5. Set Properties (Zend Server tab)
6. Enable Zend Server integration = Y
7. Zend Server URL, Use Default = N
8. Zend Server URL, URL Suffix =    /ZendServer
9. Zend Server URL, Port Number = 80
10. Authentication Password =

When I select the 'Show Server Event List' option, Zend Studio correctly opens a browser window with the Zend Server web interface displayed (with 'This feature is supported in the Zend Server Commercial Edition only'.)

Restarting Zend Studio results in the same warning message about Zend Server not detected.

I thought at first that maybe Zend Server Community Edition was not compatible with Zend Studio, but that does not seem to be the case.
Is it possible that there is a version conflict between the installed components or some Windows 7 64-bit incompatibility?  Any help would be greatly appretiated.

Comment: does zend studio requires zend server or does it requires any apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This identical question was addressed by the Zend developers on the Zend Forum here: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=5809

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey. It was me who posted the same question on Stack Overflow after receiving no replies on the Zend Forum. I have given up with Zend Studio and use Netbeans as my preferred IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with integrating Zend Studio 10.1 and Zend Server 6.3. 
The solution is to add your computer IP address in Zend Server.
You can do this in Zend Server Configuration -> Studio Integration -> Allowed hosts.